ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API : integration tests not working with gRPC
I have a Web API written with ASP.NET Core 8.0, and it's configured to work with Http1 and Http2:
"Kestrel": {
  "EndpointDefaults": {
    "Protocols": "Http1AndHttp2"
  }
}

My problem is that I cannot do any gRPC calls to it (normal HTTP ones do work), and I have no clue how to address it ("connection refused" error).
The reason for HTTP2 is to be able to do gRPC calls, I am using the protobuf-net libraries, and everything works fine, whenever I run my API, I get a couple of launch urls (http and https) and both HTTP and gRPC calls work.
My main issue is that I cannot configure my Integration Test Fixture to make it work.
First of all let me show you my Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

ServiceRegistration<AppSettings>.ConfigureServices(builder, "AdcTrains", "adc-trains",
    containerBuilderAdditionalActions:
        containerBuilder =>
        {
        },
    additionalMiddlewareActions: webApp =>
    {
        if (webApp.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            webApp.MapCodeFirstGrpcReflectionService();
        }

        webApp.MapGrpcService<TrainGrpcService>();
    },
    additionalPostBuildBehavior: async webApp =>
    {
        // write unit tests / integration tests rather than this
        var tenantIdString = "19d74b3c-2955-4667-9bc5-15d67212469e";

        var multitenantService = webApp.Services.GetRequiredService<MultitenantContainer>();
        var tenantScope = multitenantService.GetTenantScope(tenantIdString);
        var resolverService = tenantScope.Resolve<IGrpcResolverService>();
        var trainGrpcService = resolverService.ResolveService<ITrainGrpcService>(Guid.Parse(tenantIdString));
    });

/// <summary>
/// Not to be removed, used for the testing project
/// </summary>
public partial class Program 
{ }

It's pretty blank, the reason is that I use a base library written by me that enables various features, like gRPC, Redis, RabbitMQ, etc.
Within it I enable my gRPC code first
// this is actually exposing real grpc endpoints
services.AddCodeFirstGrpcReflection();

services.AddCodeFirstGrpc(config =>
  {
      config.ResponseCompressionLevel = System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Optimal;
  });

I've posted the upper excerpt just to explain how my API works and how I resolve my grpc services (just to see they init properly since Integration Testing doesn't work), now back to the integration test project.
This is my whole WebApplicationFactory, written according to the documentation
/// <summary>
/// This is the base fixture for all the integration tests
/// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-8.0
/// </summary>
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TProgram> : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram>, IAsyncLifetime where TProgram : class
{
    protected const string TenantId = "19d74b3c-2955-4667-9bc5-15d67212469e";
    // this will be initialized in InitializeAsync
    public HttpClient HttpClient = default!;

    public HubConnection WebHubConnection { get; set; }
    public HubConnection RequestHubConnection { get; set; }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseEnvironment("Test");

        builder
            //.UseTestServer()
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddCodeFirstGrpcReflection();

                services.AddCodeFirstGrpc(config =>
                {
                    config.ResponseCompressionLevel = System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Optimal;
                    config.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                });
            })
            .UseUrls("https://localhost:7034")
            .ConfigureKestrel(k => 
            {
                k.ConfigureEndpointDefaults(lo => lo.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2);
                k.ListenAnyIP(7034, listenOptions =>
                {
                    listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
                });
            })
            .Configure(app =>
            {
                app.UseRouting();

                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapGrpcService<TrainGrpcService>();
                });
            }); 
    }

    #region IAsyncLifetime
    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        HttpClient = CreateClient();

        var configuration = Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        var testConfiguration = configuration.GetSection("TestConfiguration");

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var tokenResponse = await httpClient.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
        {
            Address = testConfiguration.GetValue<string>("Ids"),
            ClientId = testConfiguration.GetValue<string>("ClientId")!,
            Scope = testConfiguration.GetValue<string>("Scope"),

            UserName = testConfiguration.GetValue<string>("UserName")!,
            Password = testConfiguration.GetValue<string>("Password")!
        });

        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokenResponse.AccessToken);
        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("tenantId", TenantId);

        // SignalR hookup
        var hubConnectionService = new HubConnectionService(configuration);

        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(15000);

        // Front-end conn
        WebHubConnection = await hubConnectionService.HubInitialize("webNotifications", tokenResponse.AccessToken, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

        // Simulating the OBS system, basically in front-end == obs just so we can test easily
        RequestHubConnection = await hubConnectionService.HubInitialize("trainRequest", tokenResponse.AccessToken, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

        if (WebHubConnection.ConnectionId is null)
            throw new Exception("Error at connecting to SignalR");

        Log.Information("Hub connectionId: {hubConnectionId}", WebHubConnection.ConnectionId);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Logout
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        var configuration = Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        var testConfiguration = configuration.GetSection("TestConfiguration");

        await HttpClient.RevokeTokenAsync(new TokenRevocationRequest
        {
            Token = HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization!.Parameter,
            Address = testConfiguration.GetValue<string>("Ids")
        });
    }
    #endregion
}

And finally the test fixture:
public class TrainGrpcConfigFixture : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>>
{
    private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;

    public TrainGrpcConfigFixture(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
        => _factory = factory;

    [Fact]
    public async Task Get_NvrSet_Response_ExpectData()
    {
        // Arrange
        var grpcResolver = _factory.Services.GetService(typeof(IGrpcResolverService)) as IGrpcResolverService;
        var trainGrpcService = grpcResolver.ResolveService<ITrainGrpcService>();
        var response = await trainGrpcService.GetNvrSetResponseAsync(new TrainConfig.Grpc.Models.Dtos.NvrSet.Requests.NvrSetRequest() { TrainId = 8 });
    }
}

Whenever it attempts to connect it fails with connection refused...
So my guess, is that for some reason my Web API doesn't start with a specific port as I've attempted to (7034) and it just plainly rejects me.
I have exhausted all my attempts before writing here, I did find some samples but they are pretty old and seem to be from around 2019~, tried including them here but they fail.... so I've just stuck with the official doc for .NET 8 which doesn't cover much related go gRPC.

Is your test application a client or a server?  You cannot listen to a port that is already being used by another app on the same machine.

My test application / SUT is a server (ASP .NET Core WebAPI).
So my Integration Test's HTTPClient can successfully dial into it, but somehow I get kicked with connrefused whenever I try with grpc

Is server just getting to the end and closing?  You can add Console.Readline() after opening the listener to stop app from closing.  Check from cmd.exe >Netstat -a and see if port is listening.

I'll make an update asap, but basically the server ends whenever the [Fact] ends, so that's fine, I think.
When I start my microservice individually, I can see logs like ('listening to http://localhost:xxx, https://localhost:xxx), but when I run it thru my Integration Test project they don't show up.

I think the server is terminating.  Yes you are starting to listen but for some reason the server is stopping.  Either that or there is no route from the client to the server.
